# Different terms for money throughout history

Tags: terminology

What different terms for money have there been throughout history?

Like:

- 孔方兄
- 上清童子

Time period used too would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 泉     战国
- 邓通   汉
- 货泉   汉
- 白水真人 汉
- 阿堵物 南北朝
- 孔方兄 晋
- 青蚨 -
- 上清童子 唐
- 没奈何 宋
- [不动尊](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=8nckMIY7wka27HkNc4-j47iyrF5Qhn5dTPw3kjYrDeLFnxzlNPkaK2IEdWSlf5t4xGegFG2_-Q5rIJc9vHBjca)
- 袁大头 民国
- 大团结 1949之后
- 毛爷爷 当代

ref [here](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_640089030100louv.html)

Comment: 没奈何 is an awesome way to refer to money: "necessary evil" lol.

Answer (score 1):

阿堵物 -"that stuff"-was popular during the 晉 period and remained a literary way to refer to money. Source: 世說新語. Interestingly I think a close variant of 阿堵 to mean "that" is still used I believed in 閩南語？

Comment: So is it ā or ē?

Comment: excellent question- I have no idea. Taiwanese people say something like "ah-nei" when they mean 那樣, and the ah-那 map seems similar to how 阿堵 means "that", so I guess a1, but I'm assuming a lot and working off memory right now. On reflection maybe the nei is what maps to 那. Spoken language is annoying.

Comment: My mouse-over dictionary says ē.